# Pandas/ Numpy (v0.19.1/ v1.11.2) dataframe performance Issues when accessing by index

Tags: performance, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-3.5

I have a function f that I pass two `pandas.DataFrames`. I'm iterating through the columns of the first one. It contains index values of the second one. The index is a string, more particularly a MD5 string like `'1950abcbdf69bc4b6da8d950e87f538f'`. I use those indexes to retrieve rows of the second dataframe. Here's the code:

```
def f(df_A, df_B):
    for row in df_A.itertuples():
        hash_index=row[1]
        fields_B = df_B.ix[hash_index].values  # <== VERY SLOW
```

It works very fine on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, VM), but due performance issues, I moved to a server VM (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), I needed more RAM). The server uses:

```
'3.5.2 (default, Dec  3 2016, 16:49:26) \n[GCC 4.9.2]'
numpy==1.11.2
pandas==0.19.1
```

My laptop has:

```
'3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
numpy==1.11.1
pandas==0.18.1
```

To mention the most relevant data. The big problem is, that the Server is way slower (factor 1000 or even more). In the code example I marked the line with "VERY SLOW". It takes the server 0.094 seconds to execute that line. `.loc[]` was even slower. Can you imagine a reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Once I've written my question I already noticed the different version of numpy and pandas. Thus I just **downgraded** the version of both packages and now it works like a charm. Thus either numpy or pandas at it's newest version is buggy here...